# How to stop a hanging UUID start job that is not listed in /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, startup, storage, uuid

On boot up the system hangs for 90 seconds for a UUID start job. This has already been answered at [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by).
The solution there involves removing the offending UUID from the `/etc/fstab`.

In my case, however, `cat /etc/fstab` does not list the offending UUIDs, nor does `blkid`.

Here is a screenshot of the hang:

[image: offending UUID 2 of 2. UIUID ends in db5aa]
[image: offending UUID 1 of 2. UIUID ends in 4b252]

And terminal for the `fstab` and `blkid`.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
PARTUUID=83e38dbb-a281-4157-9ae8-06361a40475b /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 0
PARTUUID=ab479d41-e3b9-46aa-9f1d-2a8c442b0dac /recovery vfat umask=0077 0 0
UUID=89a5c36c-2f93-4723-a1fe-f7791802190d / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ef824484-7f7c-464b-83ac-71298f8631b9 /mnt/2tb_slow auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=2tb%20slow 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/166f7ef4-e8e5-496a-8f69-6e7b65fdb5aa /mnt/120gb_fast auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=120GB%20fast 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3bdf3b47-1078-432d-9633-987de4291e60 /mnt/4tb_slow auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=4tb_slow 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca371e75713-part1 /mnt/320gb_slow auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=320gb_slow 0 0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca726c633e8-part1 /mnt/500gb_slow auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5004ae4aa2c-part1 /mnt/1TB_slow auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="89a5c36c-2f93-4723-a1fe-f7791802190d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="26fad6b9-31ed-4039-8918-c26777f7401b"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="1483-0D53" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="83e38dbb-a281-4157-9ae8-06361a40475b"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="1482-F2BD" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="recovery" PARTUUID="ab479d41-e3b9-46aa-9f1d-2a8c442b0dac"
/dev/sda: LABEL="4tb_slow" UUID="3bdf3b47-1078-432d-9633-987de4291e60" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb: LABEL="brain" UUID="ef824484-7f7c-464b-83ac-71298f8631b9" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="11005b63-b700-4c10-b836-ab0142703c64"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="b52766bf-5bf0-303d-9c85-0e9115322d95" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" LABEL="WININSTALL" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTLABEL="WININSTALL" PARTUUID="ffa5f15c-fb1d-4822-a3ad-122b6b3fe019"
/dev/sdd1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2021-02-09-19-06-26-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="38b1c112" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="38b1c112-01"
/dev/sdd2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="54C5-9C6C" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="38b1c112-02"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="backup320" UUID="88607df4-477e-4ecf-b02b-06760ace6e24" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000aff57-01"
/dev/sdg1: LABEL="500 GB slow" UUID="8e86976e-059c-44c8-8fe0-f3480530161b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="df86a2f1-5804-4515-a091-c55d0fe630ce"
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="storage" UUID="f5d68032-eae7-404c-9762-19962f97261c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="51bb1bd8-01"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
```

OS: Pop 20.10 groovy
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.0-7614-generic

Comment: Worst case - look everywhere!  `sudo find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r sudo grep -El 'uuid1|uuid2'`. I'll let you type  the UUIDs. Can't cut and paste from pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `/etc/fstab` line matches the UUID of the hanging filesystem in the first picture:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/166f7ef4-e8e5-496a-8f69-6e7b65fdb5aa /mnt/120gb_fast auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=120GB%20fast 0 0
```

The second picture has hanging mount by UUID `c04ab358-de52-4c2d-9291-3a140d74b252`, which is not mentioned anywhere in `/etc/fstab` as far as I can see. Since it's not mentioned in `blkid` output either, it's probably referring to a disk/partition that has been removed or re-`mkfs`'d for some reason, and the configuration for it needs to either be removed or corrected to match the current UUID, as appropriate.

*But in systems with `systemd`, `/etc/fstab` is not the only place that can be used to configure filesystem mounts.* It might be that someone has written a custom `*.mount` unit file in `/etc/systemd/`, or some process dynamically creates one under `/run/systemd/`.

Run `grep -ri c04ab358- /etc/systemd /run/systemd /lib/systemd` to see if the offending UUID is mentioned in a `*.mount` file anywhere.

If such a `*.mount` file is located under `/etc/systemd/`, just remove it.

If it is located under `/run/systemd/`, you'll need to examine the unit file in case it has any comments in it identifying the creator process. Since `/run` is a tmpfs filesystem, everything in there must be auto-generated or copied from elsewhere at every boot. You'll need to identify the process that creates the unit file and make it stop doing so if the resulting mount unit is not appropriate any more.

In the unlikely event the UUID is mentioned in a `*.mount` file that's been placed under `/lib/systemd/`, then someone is violating recommended system administration practice. If the file comes from a software package, send in a bug report; creating something that is clearly unique to this particular system (because of the filesystem UUID used) in `/lib/systemd/` is not appropriate. It should go into `/etc/systemd/` instead, or into `/etc/fstab` if there is no particular reason to use a custom mount unit.

Comment: `sudo grep -ri c04ab358- /run/systemd` returns:
`/run/systemd/generator/systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap.service:ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'cryptswap' '/dev/disk/by-uuid/c04ab358-de52-4c2d-9291-3a140d74b252' '/dev/urandom' 'swap,plain,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512'` sure enough, the problem UUID lies in `/etc/crypttab`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo lsblk -f` will show device, partition, UUID, size and mount point for all real devices.

Comment: These UUIDs still don't list the ones that caused the hang.